# Error when a I try to execute a package in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, ssms

Problem when I execute a package from SSMS

Hi Everyone,
I'm getting this error when i try to execute from SSMS

> microsoft samples sharepoint list source could not be loaded. The
>   exception was: Could not load type
>   MicrosoftSamples.SharePointListSource' from
>   assembly'Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost, Host, version=13.0.0.0
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=89845dcd8080cc9.

I installed SharePointListAdapter 2017 in my VS 2017 with SSIS and it's working perfect but when I schedule the job give that error.Sound like i need to install something.

Comment: whatever dependencies you installed local on your machine for whatever you developed would also need to be installed server side where the package was deployed.

Comment: Please make sure that the SQLServerAgent Account should also have all the privileges that the user account used to run the Package from SSMS/SSIS.